# Why such a small PermGen Commit increment?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, permgen

I was profiling a java functional test that was taking a long time and exhibiting occasional OOM's (in C heap, not java) and I found a really sub-optimal behavior in the java serial GC (and it probably applies to all java GC's.)

Here's a sample of Permgen statistics at full GC points from the test run (size in KB):

```
before  after   commit
167935  167935  167936
172031  172031  172032
```

As you can see, permgen space isn't getting cleaned by these full gc runs.  Not a big deal, but it points to these full gc's being useless.  Additionally, the commit value is a little funny.  I assumed the commit value for a gc log entry would be the value after the commit size was increased.  I now think it is actually the commit value prior to the full GC run.

Additionally, I think that the permgen commit size grows at a fixed, un-tunable size of 4MB (172032K - 167936K) per full GC run.  This means that if you start with a default permgen size of, say 64mb, and when your application is fully up it requires 128mb of permgen, it would require 16 full gc's for permgen to reach its final commit size.

In the case of the functional test I was profiling, 58 full gc's had to run, each taking 0.5 to 2 seconds.  By making the jvm argument -XX:PermSize equal to -XX:MaxPermSize I was able to reduce that to zero full GC's (without significantly increasing the much-much-faster new-generation gc's) and reduce the GC time reported by the gc instrumentation messages by 90%, from 90 seconds to 9 seconds.

I looked numerous places but I couldn't find a different tuning parameter for the commit size growth rate for the permgen heap. It's kind of ugly to fully allocate the maximum possible size of the permgen heap at program startup.  Does anyone know of an alternative to increasing PermSize to equal MaxPermSize that will achive similar results without allocating so much memory at startup? Why is the permgen commit increment so small and fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Permgen is not garbage collected. (Under normal circumstances). Permgen is where the actual class objects and other 'guts' of the java runtime are kept. As your application initializes and uses various classes and / or jars are loaded and /or used, those associated class files are essentially stored in permgen.

There had to have been other relevant parameters relating specifically to your app that account for your observation.

There really is no documented relationship between permgen increase and garbage collections. Permgen is for storing *static* data used by the jvm and *usually* won't be collected (Except in rare circumstances ie ClassLoader loading classes and then said ClassLoader going out of scope)

Comment: Two points: 1. Permgen size does decrease, my colleagues have observed this.  Probably related to auto-generated classes.  2. The full collection is kicked off when permgen memory pressure gets too high.  It doesn't matter whether permgen is collected or not; the jvm does a full collect when permgen commit size needs to increase.  I have very strong evidence for this given that increasing the starting permgen size reduces the number of full collects, ceteris paribus.